# How to find the distances to all buildings quickly?

Tags: performance-tuning, associations, geography, entity

I would like to create an association by mapping the function GeoDistance[Here,#]& over all buildings without missing locations in a reasonable amount of time less than 30 minutes.
I have the following line of code:

```
position=EntityValue[EntityClass["Building", All], "Position", 
    "NonMissingEntityAssociation"];
buildingdistances = 
 AssociationMap[GeoDistance[Here, #] &, Keys[position]] // 
  AbsoluteTiming
```

I would love to figure out how to make this work.

Edit:
I would also like to monitor the progress of the computation using something similar to Monitor or ProgressIndicator.

I have another question that builds on this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261263/how-to-keep-track-of-multiple-properties-of-entities).

Comment: To be clear you mean the distance from `Here` to each building in `EntityClass["Building"]`?

Comment: You should take the edits you have made to this question, remove them, and ask a completely new & separate question using the aforementioned edits you should remove from this question. Please understand that you have effectively changed the basis of this question to an entirely new one. The original question was answered, and now you can ask a new one & link to this one, instead of changing completely this question as you have done.

Comment: Sounds good. thank you

Comment: I have created a new question.

Comment: I have a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GeoDistance` automatically maps over lists, so you can do `GeoDistance[loc, {loca, locb, locc}]` and it will return the distance from `loc` to each of the second argument. It returns a `QuantityArray`, so we use `Normal` to get the `List` version, and then create the association with it. This takes about two seconds on my machine.

```
assoc = AssociationThread[
   Keys@position -> Normal@GeoDistance[Here, Values@position]];
```

However displaying an association with this many entities can cause the frontend to lock up, so you may want to do eg `Dataset[assoc]` to view the data.

Comment: How should I go about sorting the distances quickly?

Comment: I think there might be a better way than Sort.

Comment: `Sort` is the way to do it. Just `Sort@assoc` or `ReverseSort@assoc`. Again, to actually display the data, you probably want to use `Dataset[assoc]` so that it doesn't take the frontend forever to display the entities. `Sort@Dataset[assoc]` also works.

Comment: How can I combine this with the number of floors a building has? See edits above.

Comment: It is a bit frustrating having answered your question only for you to change it and add significantly more complexity to it. Perhaps someone else will be able to help you with the remainder of your question.

Comment: I like your answer I am not very familiar with associations compared to lists.